# How to set and check value of variable from inserted table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a Trigger to insert data into a table by cheking the status field from another table.

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[insercionVentasConcluidadas]

on [dbo].[pedido]
after update
as 
declare @fechaactual date
declare @estado varchar
begin 
    if UPDATE(estado)
    begin 
        select @estado = estado from inserted;

        set @fechaactual = GETDATE();
        if (@estado = 'cerrado')
        print N'RAS'
        begin

            insert into ventaConcluida(numeroPedido, nombreCliente, nombreProveedor, fechaCreacion, fechaCierre, diasTranscurridos, MontoPedido)
            select d.idPedido, d.nombreCliente, d.nombreProveedor, d.fechaPedido, @fechaactual, dbo.calculoDias(d.fechaPedido, @fechaactual),
                    d.montoPedido
            from inserted i 
            inner join deleted d
            on i.idPedido = d.idPedido

        end
    end 
end
```

What Trigger should do is to insert data on a table when variable `@estado` equals to `cerrado` after an update of the other table named `pedido` when status in that table = `cerrado`, and It sets the value with `select @estado = estado from inserted;` where allowed values are only `cerrado, creado and parcial` but actually it inserts in any of those status, so I think the problem could be setting the variable or in checking the value `if (@estado = 'cerrado')`.
The other issue is that it only inserts data with adding line `print N'RAS'`, and when the Trigger is execute it inserts the data but doesn`t print the line.

Comment: Your trigger is tragically flawed. It assumes that there will only be a single row in inserted. In SQL Server triggers fire once per operation. As such, they need to be set based. You also have varchar with no size specified....this is a bad practice. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Your `if ... print` logic puts the `begin`/`end` block with the `insert` _outside_ the `if`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @SeanLange it was that! the declaration of variable. I didn't assume that it was an important thing, that by no specifying a size it by default will set an max size. Thanks!

Comment: That is only a portion of the issue with your trigger. You need to fix the rest of it too.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment but is sufficiently important that you need to understand it clearly. You have (condensed for clarity):

```
   if (@estado = 'cerrado')
    print N'RAS'
    begin
      <do stuff>
    end
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
   if (@estado = 'cerrado')
       print N'RAS'; 

   begin
      <do stuff>
   end;
```

Your begin/end block has no relationship to the IF statement. The only thing your code does based on the IF statement is the print that follows it. And note that a production trigger should never try to return resultsets or print. It might be OK for development and debugging but not in production code.